# calendar.ui/fullCalendar - BusinessHours problem

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use calendar.ui on my project. I can bring my events using ng-model on the view but I can't bring from a rest service the business Hours and put it into calendar. Here is my view:

```
<div class="calendar" ng-if="events.length && businessHours.length" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="events"></div>
```

And here is my js:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
                calendar:{
                        header: {
                                left: 'prev,next today',
                                center: 'title',
                                right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,list'
                        },
                        nowIndicator: 'true',
                        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                        locale: 'es',
                        navLinks: true, 
                        selectable: true,
                        selectHelper: true,
                        selectOverlap: false,
                        allDaySlot: false,
                        businessHours: $scope.businessHours,
                        selectConstraint: "businessHours",
                        editable: false,
                        eventOverlap: false,
                        eventClick: $scope.eventClick,
                }
        };
```

And here is my call to a rest service on the same js

```
   post(url,data,$http,function(response) {
                    $scope.events = [response['events']];
                    $scope.businessHours = response['businessHours'];
            });
```

This is the output of that rest service call ($scope.businessHours):

```
 [{"dow":"[1]","start":"08:00:00","end":"23:59:00"},{"dow":"[2]","start":"08:00:00","end":"23:59:00"},{"dow":"[3]","start":"08:00:00","end":"23:59:00"},{"dow":"[4]","start":"08:00:00","end":"23:59:00"},{"dow":"[5]","start":"08:00:00","end":"23:59:00"},{"dow":"[6]","start":"09:00:00","end":"23:59:00"}]
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I think this is because fullCalendar isn't expecting to wait for an async function to complete before trying to read the business hours values. it expects to see the values immediately when the calendar is created. It has support for providing things like events asynchronously, but not businessHours. So you'd have to make sure you've collected the values from the server _before_ trying to create the calendar. Or, you could fetch them asynchronously but you'd have to set the option on the calendar later (when the async call completes) using this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options

Comment: Hy Adyson, thanks for the reply. I try to add this after async call but doesn't work:

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option','businessHours',$scope.horarios);

Is that the right way to use it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: that's the right way to do the fullCalendar part in a normal fullCalendar environment, but I've got no idea what you do with regards to using it in an Angular environment. I don't know if your scope variable is valid at at that time, or, if you're using fullCalendar via some kind of package, whether you've interacted with fullCalendar in the way which is expected. Angular might as well be Martian as far as I'm concerned, sorry :-)